# How to add notification Badge count in Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, methods, error-handling

I have been learning coding recently and i wanted to develop an android app .I have the vision of what it needs to do but i need some help and i am unable to implement that vision in codes, so seeking some help here. please assist of you can.

The situation here is I created a app with Bottom Navigation Activity. In the home fragment and dashboard i had used few view and web view to show or fetch the information and presented but unable to sort out the notification fragment.

In this area i wanted to display notification number and list of notification in that page. An example image for your reference. I just need that please advise how to take this forward. I would he happy if someone can assist me .

[image]

Comment: i also understand implementing the badge may not work in all devices because the android framework does not has that but can some one suggest how to get that list of notifications listed in that fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below lib it is allow to add budge into bottom Navigation

https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

Using this lib add budge following below code

```
bottomNavigation.setNotification(notification, bottomNavigation.getItemsCount() - 1);
```

Please find below result as you want

[image]

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is for highly skilled programmer friend. But i managed to run it step by step and took 2 days to figure out. But this is a good answer. Thank you so much.  Now I'm confident that I can build this feature